# breakdown of 誰もが納得するかたちで

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 勝ち取るしかないのだ。誰もが納得するかたちで。

I don't remember what the context is but i assume the speaker has to win.

Because I have to win, anyone would understand (what i'm trying to do here) ?

what exactly is かたちで?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

かたち（形）basically means form, shape, figure, etc. In this context, かたちで means **in a way that**. The speaker is saying that there is no other way but for him/her/them to win (earn, gain, etc.), and that s/he/they must do it in a way that is acceptable to everyone.

Other examples of 形で:

> 目に見{み}える形{かたち}で社会{しゃかい}に貢献{こうけん}したい

(I'd) like to contribute to the society in a visible manner

> コンピューターで読{よ}み取{と}れる形{かたち}で整理{せいり}する

Organize in a form that can be read in a computer

Answer (score 1):

形(かたち) can be translated as "way" or "form"
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/形/#je-12491](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%BD%A2/#je-12491)

So the translation becomes:
誰もが納得するかたちで
In a way that anybody agrees.