# What does 形になります mean here?

Tags: set-phrases

『その隙を、ステージ部門二位につけた来禅が衝いたというわけですね。特に模擬店部門のメイドカフェの得票数が凄まじい！審査の際に物議を醸したという話ですが、実行委員の熱心なプッシュが功を奏した**形になります**ね！』

The host was announcing that the champion school at a school festival was 来禅高校, whose maid cafe won them a lot of votes.

Hi. What does 形になります mean here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase has very low searchability so that I might miss one or two duplicate questions on this site (somewhat close [one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61295/7810)), but...

形 has [a definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%A2_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%29/) among formal noun usages:

> **３** 物事の結果としての状態。「どっちつかずの―になる」

Formal nouns are usually appositive not translating very well into English:

> 実行委員の熱心なプッシュが功を奏した形になります
> lit. "It would be a consequence that the (festival) committee members' eager push paid off"
> ≈ *the committee members' hard push has contributed a lot to this result*